# How do we know the sign for the ln?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I used the $f'(x)/f(x)$ standard form to integrate the following:
$$\int \frac{\cot(x)}{\ln(\sin x)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \ln|\ln\sin(x)| + C$$
However, the correct answer involved removing the modulus sign and specifying a negative sign instead:
$$\int \frac{\cot(x)}{\ln(\sin x)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \ln[|\ln\sin(x)|] + C = \ln[-\ln(\sin x)] +C$$
How do we know that $\ln \sin(x)$ is negative?

Comment: Check what is the range of $\sin x$, and then check when $\ln$ is negative.

Comment: When $t$ is not Positive , $\log(t)$ is not valid. When $t$ is between $0$ & $1$ , $\log(t)$ is negative. We can make it Positive Either by Modulus Sign or by Negative Sign. We can then take Either $\log(|\log(t)|)$ or $\log(-\log(t))$ which are Entirely Equivalent in that Case.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $-1\leqslant \sin(x)\leqslant 1$ for all real number $x$. The composition $\ln(\sin(x))$ only make sense over the interval $]0,1]$ and over that interval the map $x\mapsto \ln(x)$ have range over the negative real number. However,  the answer should be $\ln|\ln(\sin(x))|+C$ of course.

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer, where $\ln(\sin(x))$ has to be negative since 0<sin(x)⩽1 for the ln to be defined. But for the last sentence, do you mean that the answer can be either $\ln|\ln(\sin(x))|+C$ or $\ln[−\ln(\sin(x))]+C$, where the second answer makes sense too because adding the negative sign makes $\ln(\sin(x))$ positive?

Comment: Sophie I prefer the answer where we use the absolute value which is natural because  $\int \frac{\cot x}{\ln \sin x}\, dx\overset{u(x):= \ln \sin x}{=} \int\frac{1}{u}\, du=\ln |u|+C=\ln |\ln \sin x|+C$. But yes, you can use the second version.